# Munin quota usage

Tags: munin, quota

I'm trying to get Munin to report quota usage but it's not working. On top of quota_usage_ it says:

```
# Usage: place in /etc/munin/node.d/quota-usage_<dev> (or link it there using
# ln -s), for example quota-usage_hda3. Use underscores instead of slashes, for
# example to monitor /dev/mapper/vol-foo, name this quota-usage_mapper_vol-foo
```

So I did just that but it doesn't seem to work.

munin-node.log says:

```
2011/11/25-11:05:08 [23728] Error output from quota_usage_:
2011/11/25-11:05:08 [23728]     Can't exec "/etc/munin/plugins/quota_usage_": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Munin/Node/Service.pm line 215, <STDIN> line 87.
2011/11/25-11:05:08 [23728]     # ERROR: Failed to exec.
2011/11/25-11:05:08 [23728] Service 'quota_usage_' exited with status 42/0.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm running Debian 6 in case it matters. I have it symlinked as `quota-usage_xvda` (it's running on a Xen VPS) and `repquota /dev/xvda` runs just fine.

Update - got it working by putting it into /etc/munin/plugins/ and setting it to run as root (as Dom suggested) but I now get this in munin-graph.log:

```
2011/11/25 18:15:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/cache/munin/www/xxx/xxx/quota_usage_xvda-week.png : opening '/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd': No such file or directory
```

After some research it looks like that's a bug:
http://munin-monitoring.org/ticket/794

Editing as the diff shows fixes it but I only get 2 users reported in the graphs now instead of the roughly dozen I have. Oh well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `quota-usage_xvda`. If it works, you have to add the root user in your munin-node.conf for this plugin. You can then check by `munin-run quota-usage_xvda`.
Check if your repquota is in /usr/sbin/ directory (as it is hard coded in the plugin).
Are you sure that the link is good ? The quota_usage_ should be outside of /etc/munin/plugins dir

Comment: The instructions in the plugin say to place it into /etc/munin/node.d/ which is what I did but it did not run from there. I put it into /etc/munin/plugins/ (where I had it originally when I had that error) but it looks like when I tried it first I forgot to set it to run as root so it didn't work. Setting it to run as root and from inside /etc/munin/plugins/ works now but it errors out on graphs now... Any idea why that could be? I put the error in the original question.